# How to generate a random real under a specified density function?

Tags: random

I want to generate a random real in the interval [0,1] according to the density function f(x) = 2x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look up [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) and [`RandomVariate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html). With `ProbabilityDistribution`, either give it an already normalized PDF or use `Method -> "Normalize"`.

Comment: I am able to generate a random number  according to any of the parametric distribution functions in Mathematica by using RandomVariate and ProbabilityDistribution.  But I don't know how to get a random number according to a specific density function like f(x) = 2x.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer check the links in the answer; your problem is tackled adequately there (see esp. sections *Scope>Distribution specification* and *Options>Method* on the first link); notice how you can use `ProbabilityDistribution[...]` where you'd use eg `NormalDistribution[]`

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer `ProbabilityDistribution` does precisely what you are asking for. Please look at the doc page examples.